# get the universal time zone in java script?

Tags: javascript, datetime

this is my javascript code:

```
 var player = GetPlayer();
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getUTCDate(); 
player.SetVar("day1", day);
var month = currentDate.getUTCMonth()+1;
player.SetVar("month1", month);
var year = currentDate.getUTCFullYear();
player.SetVar("year1", year);

var yearexpire=2014;
var monthexpire=9;
var dayexpire=17;

player.SetVar("yearexpire1",  yearexpire);
player.SetVar("monthexpire1",  monthexpire);
player.SetVar("dayexpire1",  dayexpire);

if (year<yearexpire){
player.SetVar("expired",false);
}
else if(year=yearexpire){
if (month<monthexpire){
player.SetVar("expired","false");
}
else if(month=monthexpire){
if (day<dayexpire){
player.SetVar("expired","false");
};
};
};
```

this code show me the date but when i changed the date on my platform will appear the changed date not the universal, so i need the universal not the local date i think here can use MDN or something like that any suggestions please

Comment: get the time from a server. almost any server includes the `date` header on all ajax calls

Answer (score 1):

With Node.js it would be something like this .. I think.

```
npm init
npm install --save express
node server.js
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/time', function(req, res) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
   res.json({date: new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')});
   // sends { "date": "2017-01-22 20:58:19" }

});

app.listen('3000', 'localhost');

console.log('Server: http://localhost:3000/');
```

app.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
      var date = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).date;
      console.log('DATE: ' + date);
   }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/time', true);
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, get the time from server as string with timezone , parse it in javascript. You might want to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) lib for parsing.